# html javascript listar dados json em <ul> <li>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Pessoal peço uma ajuda dos amigos:

o código faz uma requisição ajax para pegar dados de uma api (json)e passar por todos os objetos dentro do array

> meu json= [{Nome:"Ajato 2000"}, {Nome:"Crystal I"} ]

no caso como faço para listar ou imprimir os dados com html usando um atributo de lista sei fazer isso com php mais com html sei que e tipo assim

> document.getElementById('exibir').value;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "https://coarinet.com/kibarcos/api",
  success: function(data) {


   
  for (var i in data) { 

  Nomes= data[i]["Nome"];

}



  }
});
</script>
 
<p id="id_nome"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por gentileza, amigo, releia a sua pergunta e pergunte-se a si mesmo se é possível alguém entender claramente o que se deseja. Estamos aqui para ajudar mesmo, mas a pergunta é tão carente de informações que torna inviável uma resposta objetiva. Talvez até consiga uma resposta, mas com certeza depois vão debater bastante nos comentários até se saber o que vc realmente queria, e isso já poderia ter sido informado na própria pergunta.

Comment: Modifiquei sera que agora ficou melhor ? ...  pessoal peço mil desculpas pela interpretação

Comment: `for(x in data){ document.getElementById('id_' + data[x]).innerHTML = data[x] }`, assim deve funcionar, mas sua resposta está muito vaga. Posta seu `JSON`

Comment: Ja alterei coloquei o meu json pra ficar melhor pessoal de entender

Comment: @kibarconet dá uma olhada na minha resposta, ela conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi você irá receber um objeto JSON e quer exibi-lo dentro de uma lista, correto?

Então você pode fazer algo do tipo.

```js
let nomes = document.getElementById('nomes')
const listaNomes = [
  { nome: 'Eduardo' },
  { nome: 'José' },
  { nome: 'Ribeiro' },
  { nome: 'Soares'}
]

listaNomes.forEach(obj => {
  nomes.innerHTML += `<li>${ obj.nome }</li>`
})
```

```html
<ul id="nomes"></ul>
```

Explicando um pouco, crie uma tag `ul` com um `id` qualquer, no caso coloquei como `nomes`.

Assumi que o JSON que você recebe é algo como o `listaNomes`, então nele basta criar um laço de repetição, poderia ser `for`, `while`, `map` e etc, porém escolhi o `forEach` e depois basta usar o `innerHTML` no `ul`, que ele irá injetar o código dentro de sua tag.

Obs: `${}` -> é um novo recurso do JavaScript conhecido como `template string`, que nada mais é que uma forma de concatenar strings. Você pode saber mais [AQUI](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)